# Android: Toast is not showing before system.exit()

Tags: android, toast

I have nested nested class where I am trying to display a toast for the outer most class before I exit the app. The toast works just fine if I comment out exit statement, so I know I'm accessing the context correctly. I have also tried putting the toast in a thread where it sleeps for 2000 ms (and vice versa for the exit statement), but that still does not work.

All I want to do display a toast and exit the program. (It would be nice to do it simultaneously, if possible...)

```
public class A extends Service {
   
    private Context context;
    
    //...

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        context = this;
        //...
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    Handler disToast = new Handler(new Callback() {

         @Override
         public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "see ya", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;//also tried false, but that did not work...
        }
   });

   private Runnable r = new Runnable() {

       public void run() {


           new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

               public void onFinish() {

                   Message msg=disToast.obtainMessage();
                   msg.obj="my message";
                   disToast.sendMessage(msg);
          
                   handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
                   System.exit(0);
               }
           }.start();//end of inner most class
            
    };//end of first inner class

}//outermost class
```

I'm not working with any Activities (outer most class is a `Service`, and the two inner are normal Java classes) so some of the answers do not work.

Comment: `context = getApplicationConext();`

Comment: Don't use System.exit

Comment: @barq Mind telling me what I should use then to terminate the program?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149501/how-to-close-the-activity-from-the-service

Comment: @MD I get a "cannot resolve method" error when I try that...perhaps because the outer most class is a Service? I'm not sure...

Answer (score 0):

USE getApplicationConext() INSTEAD OF CONTEXT

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationConext(), "Timer up. Existing app...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I get a "cannot resolve method" error when I try that...perhaps because the inner most class is not an activity?

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler disToast= new Handler(new Callback() {
   @Override 
   public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
             String mString=(String)msg.obj;
             Toast.makeText(this, mString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
});

 private Runnable r = new Runnable() {


    public void run() {


        new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

            public void onFinish() {



            Message msg=disToast.obtainMessage();
            msg.obj="your message";
            disToast.sendMessage(msg);

                handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }.start();

};
```

More details Refer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769414/how-can-i-put-toast-in-a-runnable-of-a-service)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried that (with some modifications so it would compile) but it does not work. I have updated my code above...

Comment: That does not work either, unfortunately. I should also note that the 2nd parameter for makeText gives me an error if its a Message type, rather than a String.

Comment: Message msg=disToast.obtainMessage();
            msg.obj="your message";
            disToast.sendMessage(msg);

Comment: I tried that...did not work. I have updated the code again

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that does not work either. Also, handleMessage would return a boolean, assuming it is imported from android.os.Handler.Callback;

Answer (score -1):

please use

`Toast.LENGTH_LONG` instead of

```
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT


 Toast.makeText(context, "Timer up. Existing app...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Now your toast will be display after System.exit();

Comment: Thank you for the response, but that unfortunately does not work. :(